# How can I match the check marks for the topping table to be the same as the order form?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am new to Jquery.  This is for class, but I am going beyond the assignment so I can learn.

I am trying to have the toppings check marks in each table cell reflect the person's order.

Although I have check marks, I set the JQuery code up so that it recognizes one topping at a time as a **simple test**. Once the simple test works, I will proceed with selecting multiple toppings.

The problem I am having is: the topping the person selects goes to the next order.

For example:
**Order 1:** I choose vanilla, I select **nuts**, and click "add order" button
no check marks are selected.

**Order 2:** I choose vanilla I select sprinkles, and click "add order" button.
**nuts** gets a checkmark, but the checkmark shows up in in **order 1** toppings table cell.

I would appreciate any suggestions. https://jsfiddle.net/aLst8drx/

**HTML:**

```
<head>
<!--jQuery CDN -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <fieldset>
        <br>

        <!--asks for name-->
        <label for="nameInput">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="nameInput" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" />
        <br>

        Ice cream flavor:    
        <!--asks for flavor type-->
        <select name="flavor" id="flavor">
            <option value="#">Please select a flavor</option>
            <option value="0" id="vanilla">Vanilla: $2.00</option>
            <option value="1" id="chocolate">Chocolate: $2.00</option>
            <option value="2" id="strawberry">Strawberry: $2.25</option>
            <option value="3" id="pistachio">Pistachio: $2.25</option>
        </select>

        <br><br>

        Select your toppings:
       <br>

       <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="nuts" value = "0">Nuts:&nbsp;$.50&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="sprinkles" value="1">Sprinkles&nbsp;$.50&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="fudge" value="2">Hot Fudge&nbsp;$.50&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" id="cherry" value="3">Cherry:&nbsp;$.10

       <br>

       <label>&nbsp;</label>
       <input type="button" id="addOrderBtn" value="Add Order">

       <br>

    </fieldset>
    </form>
    <br>

    <h2>Receipt</h2>
    <br>
    <div id="receiptT">
        <table>  
           <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Item Number</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Flavor</th>
                <th>Toppings</th>
               </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
// if errors JavaScript will stop running
"use strict";

// Global Variables
var nameInput = "";
var vals = "0"; // default: no toppings: for AJAX and receipt purposes
var flavor; 
var flavorOptionID; // eceipt purposes
var toppingsName; // for receipt purposes
var itemNumber; // for receipt purposes
var outDisplay; // AJAX purposes

// arrays
var namesInputsHolder =[]; // holds each customer's name
var flavorNamesHolder = []; // holds each flavor
var flavorCostsHolder = []; // holds each flavor cost
var toppingsNameHolder = [];  // holds toppings

// ready event: short way
$(function() {
    $("#nameInput").focus(); // places cursor in name field

    $("select").change(processOrder); // select tags
    $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).change(processOrder); // checkbox tags

    // calculates total cost
    $("#addOrderBtn").click(function() {
        if ($("#flavor").val() == "#") {
            alert ("Please select a flavor");
        } else {
            receipt(); // calls function
        }
     }); // end of addOrderBtn     
}); // end of ready event handler

// toppings checkbox to get values
var selectedCheckbox = function(){
    var checkboxes = $("input[name='toppings']:checked");
    vals = "0"; // resets vals

    for (var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            vals += checkboxes[i].value;
        }
    }

    // grabs dropdown selected flavor ID 
    flavorOptionID = $("#flavor").find('option:selected').attr('id');
}

var processOrder = function() {
    // declaring local variables

    // gets id: value from HTML page
    flavor = $("#flavor").val(); 
    selectedCheckbox(); // calls function

};  

// table to display list
var receipt = function() { 
    var totalList = 0;
    //toppingsID = ""; // need to reset toppings so previous order is seperate from new order

    nameInput = $("#nameInput").val(); // gets id: name value from HTML page

    // adds new item to the end of the array using push method
    namesInputsHolder.push(nameInput); // adds name
    flavorNamesHolder.push(flavorOptionID); // adds flavor Name
    toppingsNameHolder.push(vals); // adds toppings value to array

    // i retrieves each element from the array
    for (var i = 0; i < namesInputsHolder.length; i++) { 
        totalList = "<tr><td class='rowId'>" + (i+1) + "</td><td>" + namesInputsHolder[i] + "</td><td>" + flavorNamesHolder[i] + "</td><td class='toppingsC'><input type='checkbox' class='nutsR' disabled>Nuts<input type='checkbox' class='sprinklesR' disabled>Sprinkles<br><input type='checkbox' class='fudgeR' disabled>Hot Fudge<input type='checkbox' class='cherryR' disabled>Cherry</td><td>";  

        $(".toppingsC").each(function(i){
            if (toppingsNameHolder[i] == "00") {
                $(".nutsR")[i].checked = true; 
                console.log($(".nutsR").length);
            }

            if (toppingsNameHolder[i] == "01") {
                $(".sprinklesR")[i].checked = true; 
            }

            if (toppingsNameHolder[i] == "02") {
                $(".fudgeR")[i].checked = true; 
            }

            if (toppingsNameHolder[i] == "03") {
                $(".cherryR")[i].checked = true;  
            }
        });

    // disables checkbox cell
    $(".toppingsCell").attr("disabled", true);
   };

    $("table > tbody").append(totalList); // table: tbody: children

}
```

Comment: Thank you Vaibhav for  taking the time to edit my question.  I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Thank you Brian for taking the time to edit my question. I really appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// if errors JavaScript will stop running
"use strict";

// Global Variables
var nameInput = "";
var vals = "0"; // default: no toppings: for AJAX and receipt purposes
var flavor; 
var flavorOptionID; // eceipt purposes
var toppingsName; // for receipt purposes
var vals; // for AJAX and receipt purposes
var itemNumber; // for receipt purposes
var outDisplay; // AJAX purposes

// arrays
var namesInputsHolder =[]; // holds each customer's name
var flavorNamesHolder = []; // holds each flavor
var flavorCostsHolder = []; // holds each flavor cost
var toppingsNameHolder = [];  // holds toppings
var flavourNameObj={"0":"chocolate","1":"vanilla","2":"strawberry","3":"pistachio"}
// ready event: short way
// long way: $(document).ready(function()){
$(function() {
    $("#nameInput").focus(); // places cursor in name field

    $("select").change(processOrder); // select tags
    $( "input[type=checkbox]" ).change(processOrder); // checkbox tags

    // calculates total cost
    $("#addOrderBtn").click(function() {
        if ($("#flavor").val() == "#") {
            alert ("Please select a flavor");
        } else {
            receipt(); // calls function
        }
    }); // end of addOrderBtn     
}); // end of ready event handler


// toppings checkbox to get values
var selectedCheckbox = function(){
    var checkboxes = $("input[name='toppings']:checked");
    vals = "0";
        for (var i=0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            vals += checkboxes[i].value;
            }
        }

    // grabs dropdown selected flavor ID 
    flavorOptionID = $("#flavor").find('option:selected').attr('id');

}

var processOrder = function() {
    // declaring local variables

    // gets id: value from HTML page
    flavor = $("#flavor").val(); 
    selectedCheckbox(); // calls function

};  

// table to display list
var receipt = function() {
var name = $("#nameInput").val();
var flavor = flavourNameObj[$("#flavor").val()];
var toppingsArr = [] 
var nutsChked = $("#nuts").is(":checked");
var sprinklesChked = $("#sprinkles").is(":checked");
var fudgeChked = $("#fudge").is(":checked");
var cherryChked = $("#cherry").is(":checked");
var rowNo = $("#receiptT").find("tbody").find("tr").length+1


var nutHtml = "<input type='checkbox' class='nutsR' disabled>Nuts";
if(nutsChked){
 nutHtml = "<input type='checkbox' checked="+nutsChked+" class='nutsR' disabled>Nuts";
}

var sprinklesHtml = "<input  type='checkbox' class='sprinklesR' disabled>Sprinkles<br>"
if(sprinklesChked){
sprinklesHtml = "<input  checked="+sprinklesChked+" type='checkbox' class='sprinklesR' disabled>Sprinkles<br>"
}

var fudgeRHtml = "<input type='checkbox'  class='fudgeR' disabled>Hot Fudge"
if(fudgeChked){
fudgeRHtml = "<input type='checkbox'  checked="+fudgeChked+" class='fudgeR' disabled>Hot Fudge"
}

var cherryRHtml = "<input type='checkbox' class='cherryR' disabled>Cherry</td><td>";
if(cherryChked){
cherryRHtml = "<input type='checkbox' checked="+cherryChked+" class='cherryR' disabled>Cherry</td><td>";
}


var totalList = "<tr><td class='rowId'>" + rowNo + "</td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + flavor + "</td><td class='toppingsC'>"
                +nutHtml+sprinklesHtml+fudgeRHtml+cherryRHtml+"</tr>"

$("#receiptT").find("tbody").append(totalList);

    }

















https://jsfiddle.net/aLst8drx/2/  

here is the working fiddle ... . ..
```

Comment: Thank you so much Prashant.  I really appreciate your help.  I knew I had a timing issue, but I could not figure how to get the check marks to be checked before it was append to the total list. :) Thank you for suggesting the flavourNameObj.  Just learned that in class. :)

Comment: Was there a reason why you put:  var toppingsArr = [] ?

Comment: Atually thats an unused variable. you can ignore

Comment: I posted another question, if you don't mind, would you mind taking a look at it?